# How to find letters in order from a string in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

For a project I'm making in Python 2.7, I have to write something that can tell if the letters "i" and "a" appear in a string put in by the user. The letters have to be in that order, but they do not have to be sequential (there can be other letters in between). How would I be able to code it so that it can detect that set of conditions in the string?

So far what I have is this...

```
name = easygui.enterbox("string being searched");
term1 = "i";
number = name.find(term1)
term2 = "a";
number = name.find(term2)
if(number > 1):
    easygui.msgbox("message")
    bonus = True
else:
    bonus = False
```

... but it doesn't take into account the order of the letters. I've gone through many similar types of questions, but nothing has quite worked.

Comment: Can there be more than one "i" or "a" in the string? What is the expected result for those cases?

Answer (score 1):

You'd find out where (and if) the first letter first appears and then search from that location for the second letter.

str.find has an optional start paramter which you can use to specify where the search for the second letter should start.

Answer (score 1):

The `find` string method gives you the index of the first occurrence of a substring. If it can't find it, it returns -1.

```
name = easygui.enterbox("string being searched")
term1 = 'i'
term2 = 'a'
position1 = name.find(term1)
position2 = name.find(term2)
if(position1 != -1 and position2 != -1 and position1 < position2):
    easygui.msgbox("message")
    bonus = True
else:
    bonus = False
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked great, and I appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad I could help! Please accept the answer as correct if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, the find method returns the index. This can be useful though. Instead of using the `number` value which gets overwritten in the original code, just check for membership.We can do this with `in` inside an if statement.

```
# set the value as a string just for easy use
name = 'i am super'

# check for membership of both "i" and "s"
if 'i' in name and 's' in name:

    # Now use the .find method to check the indexes and make sure they are in the order you want (i before a or in this case s).
    if name.find('i') < name.find('s'):

        # print the indexes just to 2x check
        print(name.find('i'))
        print(name.find('s'))

        # if both conditions are valid, print True, here's where you'd assign bonus to True
        print('True')
    else:
        # print or assign bonus to false.
        print('False')
```